# how to generate unique id in php based on current data and time?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, unique-key

I need to generate a unique ID in php based on current date and time to keep a log of when i am running code.
i.e. every time i run the code it should be able to generate a unique id based on current date and time.

Hope I am clear with my ques. How to do that?

Comment: use time stamp, its always unique

Comment: http://codepad.org/LGM4MjX2 , timestamps

Comment: @amitchhajer are you sure there won't be any conflict if i run the code any number of times and any day?

Comment: check answer, add mt_rand() if you need to make sure about random values, time should do the work too.

Comment: Oh my God... How can Unix timestamps with a 1-second resolution be unique?

Comment: why you guys think the time stamp won't be unique (not saying you are wrong), so same time in a timezone will never come again ,so a unix time stamp for that time is generated only once, right?

Comment: @amitchhajer Call same function 5 times in 0.0002s. Unix timestamp will be the same, as it's same second. Also run 2 processes at exact same time (e.g. 2 parallel requests) - timestamp is for all processes. You are very wrong.

Comment: @amitchhajer Same your example, just with more calls: http://codepad.org/Isj2lCnd

Comment: agreed, I was so wrong!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using time() to create sortable unique id's

Concatenating strings will also further randomize your desired result and still keep it sortable. manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

```
$uniqueId= time().'-'.mt_rand();
```

Answer (score 4):

With PHP 7 you can use this to generate a sufficiently random value based on the current timestamp:

```php
$s = time() . bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
```

Do note that after 265 years (starting with 11 digits in 2286) the timestamp would get another digit, and sorting order will be off; if your code is expected to survive for that long, you may want to consider some padding.

#### Old answer

You can use a combination of `uniqid()` and `time()` like so:

```
$s = uniqid(time(), true);
```

Example output:

```
1346136883503c6b3330caf5.19553126
```

Comment: We can also complexify the generation of a unique id with the function md5 `md5(uniqid(time(), true))`.

Comment: "does not guarantee uniquenes" ; "Use more_entropy to increase **likelihood** of uniqueness". So it's not really unique, but the conflict will be less probable.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?
[uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

From the doc:

Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

Comment: will it generate uniqueid() based on time only?? if so what happens if there is a time conflict...i am not clear.. i need a manual code that generates unique id every time i run the code @Mythril

Comment: You'll possibly get the same ID if your IDs are generated on the same microsecond. It's difficult but could happen. You can make it harder by appending a random string--the base technique is good IMHO.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php the doc indicates that you can provide a prefix and an entropy source.

Comment: what do they mean by prefix string? I dont get it.. entropy too.. @Mythril

Comment: A prefix is an arbitrary string that you provide to give the id extra meaning/differentiate it (it's up to you really). An entropy source is just an additional number (preferably random or pseudo-random) that will make the id less likely to collide with previously generated ids.

Comment: have you tried 'time().'-'.mt_rand();'.. can you ensure uniqid() gives a better result than this? i mean what is the best way.. no offence.

Comment: do you want to store Id's in sorted order?